# Ruby Tempfile doesn't Create File on Disk

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

I'm currently running this code on Ruby.

```
file = Tempfile.new(['tempemail', '.html'])
file << email # Email is a Ruby String (not nil)

Launchy.open(file.path)
```

Launchy is complaining that the file does not exist. I've run cat and confirmed this. Is there some way to force Ruby to save the Tempfile to disk?

EDIT:

I've done one additional test. I added a file.rewind and file.read before Launchy.open. The file successfully has the contents of email.

Comment: Can you print file.path?

Comment: Sure thing. It's "/var/folders/1r/84k38sw54fbcgrh9hlgvt8b80000gn/T/tempemail20141230-10511-2gj1yp.html" or some variation of. I should give some info on my setup. Ruby 2.1.2 under RVM on Mavericks.

Comment: What happens if you add a `file.flush` before the Launchy open?

Comment: Launchy still complains and the file still doesn't exist on disk (according to cat)

Comment: If you add `file.close`?

Comment: I've tried doing a file.close before the Launchy.open and afterwards (before the file.unlink). Neither worked.

Comment: That's bizarre. Why don't you just try not using Tempfile?

Comment: I like the properties of a tempfile. Basically, I want to make a file, have Launchy open it in a browser, and then delete the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try a `file.close`.

Test without Launchy:

```
require 'tempfile'
file = Tempfile.new(['tempemail', '.html'])
file << 'xx' # Email is a Ruby String (not nil)

file.close #<- This is needed

p File.read(file.path) # -> 'xx'
```

Without the `file.close` you get an empty string.

Instead of `close` you may also use `flush` if you continue to write data into the file:

```
require 'tempfile'
file = Tempfile.new(['tempemail', '.html'])
file << "xx\n" # Email is a Ruby String (not nil)

p file.path
file.flush

file << "yy\n" # Email is a Ruby String (not nil)
file.flush

p File.read(file.path)
```

Comment: He just said in the comments that this doesn't work, and technically, the `file.close` should delete the file.

Comment: I also tried doing a `cat #{file.path}` in the script. Worked fine. Seems to be an issue with Launchy. Thanks a lot Linuxios and knut!

Comment: @Astephen2, I just have the same problem now. I cannot even make `sh.cat #{tempfile.path}` work. I also fail to use `system("open #{tempfile.path}")`. It looks like that `Tempfile` only allows the user to manipulate it as a File object, not as an external file, in the Ruby script. So it's not `Launchy`'s fault.